# Single click to open menu for tray icon in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

How do i force a context menu for a tray icon to be shown when it is click rather than just right-clicked.

Ive tried using the MouseClick event, but the eventargs have the mouse position at x0y0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
```

Comment: Also, if you need to move the content around you could always do X +/- 10 or something

Answer (score 11):

An alternate method that I have found to work a bit better:

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = typeof(NotifyIcon).GetMethod("ShowContextMenu", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            mi.Invoke(notifyIcon1, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works well because it makes left-click behave _exactly_ like right-click (positioning, behaviour etc).

In my code I stored a private reference to the method returned by the `GetMethod` call in the app constructor, to avoid doing reflection calls on every click.