# How to open tray popup like 'Sound Control' or 'Action Center'

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm writing a winform app that lives in the notification tray and the user can open/close it by interacting with the notifyIcon control.

Whene some events happens, I need to notify the user about but the notifyIcon's BalloonTip is not enough, because I need to display a collection of messages paired with buttons, that the user must click in order to acknowledge the app that he **really saw it**(very serious stuff)

[image: action center popup]

How can I accomplish that? Does winforms provide a specific API? If there's not such API, how do I set up a completely blank form?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834907/single-click-to-open-menu-for-tray-icon-in-c-sharp). The `notifyIcon1_Click` displays a context menu at the mouse position. In your case you need to display a form.

I think the screenshot you put shows a regular form without the title bar. So you just have to make a new form and show it at the mouse position when the user clicks the notification icon.

To remove the title bar from a form just do this `form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;` or `form.ControlBox = false;
form.MaximizeBox = false;
form.MinimizeBox = false;
form.Text = "";`

Comment: So no API exist, but it's a cleaned up form?

Comment: @Pizzaboy It certainly looks like a form...and I never heard of notification form. These guys aparently had the same problem as you: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/990468-c-remove-titlebarclose-button/

Answer (score 1):

As @dburner said

```
form.ControlBox = false;
form.MaximizeBox = false;
form.MinimizeBox = false;
form.Text = "";
```

worked for me. However the first option doesn't give the aero feel.